# Scala java.io toArray error when zipping feature importance vector to column names array

Tags: java, scala, apache-spark, java-io, lightgbm

When trying to zip the feature importance vector from lightGBM `getfeatureImportances` to column names array, i ran into an error below:

```scala
import com.microsoft.ml.spark.LightGBMClassificationModel
import org.apache.spark.ml.classification.RandomForestClassificationModel

def getFeatureImportances(inputContainer: PipelineModelContainer): (String, String) = {
    val transformer = inputContainer.pipelineModel.stages.last

    val featureImportancesVector = inputContainer.params match {
        case RandomForestParameters(numTrees, treeDepth, featureTransformer) =>
            transformer.asInstanceOf[RandomForestClassificationModel].featureImportances
        case LightGBMParameters(treeDepth, numLeaves, iterations, featureTransformer) => 
            transformer.asInstanceOf[LightGBMClassificationModel].getFeatureImportances("split")
    }

    val colNames = inputContainer.featureColNames
    val sortedFeatures = (colNames zip featureImportancesVector.toArray).sortWith(_._2 > _._2).zipWithIndex
}
```

I am getting this error with reference to the last line of my code:

```
value toArray is not a member of java.io.Serializable
```

Seems like the light GBM feature importances cannot be transformed to an array. This code works fine if its just the randomForestClassifier feature importance. What other things can i do?

Comment: Can't you move `.toArray` call from the `zip` argument to the `transformer.asInstanceOf[RandomForestClassificationModel].featureImportances` expression? This way featureImportancesVector should become `Array[Double]` instead of `Serializable` if I understood the sources correctly.

Comment: Hi, this works! thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the two branches of the `match` block,
one [returns `Array[Double]`](http://mmlspark.azureedge.net/docs/scala/index.html#com.microsoft.ml.spark.LightGBMClassificationModel@getFeatureImportances(importanceType:String):Array[Double]),
another [returns `Vector`](https://spark.apache.org/docs/2.2.1/api/java/org/apache/spark/ml/classification/RandomForestClassificationModel.html#featureImportances--).

The common super type of the two types is `java.io.Serializable`,
so Scala inferred the type of the variable `featureImportancesVector` to that.
`toArray` is not available in that type,
despite that the method exists in both cases.

To fix this is easy, as suggested in the comment, move the `.toArray` to the `featureImportances`,
so that the type of both branches, and thus the type of the variable, become `Array[Double]`.